# How to ensure data refresh in a Composable when returning to it in Jetpack Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a Composable which needs to fetch some data from my local Room Database when called. When I navigate to another Composable and then navigate back it should fetch the data again.

I fetch the data in a LaunchedEffect Block. And I'm using the [Compose Destinations](https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations) Library to navigate.

```
@Composable
fun DataScreen(navigator: DestinationsNavigator) {
    val viewModel = viewModel<DataScreenViewModel>()
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.fetchData()
    }

    Button(onClick = { navigator.navigate(EditScreenDestination) }) {
        Text("Edit")
    }
}
```

Now when I navigate away from this Composable and navigate back to it using `navigator.popBackStack()` I want to refetch the Data because it might have been changed.

Is there a way I can detect that the user navigated back in my DataScreen Composable?
Or is there a better way to achieve this.

Comment: the way you do it now should also work as the LaunchedEffect will be launched again when the composable is recomposed

Comment: Why isn't your [data layer](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/data-layer) already providing a reactive stream of data (e.g., a Kotlin `Flow`) that would mean that every layer automatically updates when the data changes? You shouldn't ever be manually refreshing things...

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ah interesting I didn't know about Kotlin Flows. Apparantly there is also an integration of [Flow with Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-flow-273acffe5b57) where the DAO returns a Flow which will emit new values every time the database is updated. I will try that out.

Comment: @zaidkhan oh you are right. I checked again and the LaunchedEffect does indeed get executed. Then I must have made a mistake somwhere else in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to share more context about how your project is structured, as there might be more elegant options, but you have a few options that should work regardless.

It appears you are using a Fragment or an Activity, so you could either of the following:

1. Register the ViewModel as a lifecycle observer of the Fragment or Activity and do a new fetch when onStart is called
2. Make the Fragment or Activity call `fetchData` in the onStart callback

For both options, you would remove the "LaunchedEffect" block from the Composable

Comment: This would not work as I am only navigating between Composables not between Fragments or Activities.

Answer (score 0):

Add this helper to your project:

```
package xxxxxxxxxxxx
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavOptions
import androidx.navigation.NavOptionsBuilder
import androidx.navigation.Navigator

/**
 * The navigation result callback between two call screens.
 */
typealias NavResultCallback<T> = (T) -> Unit

// A SavedStateHandle key is used to set/get NavResultCallback<T>
private const val NavResultCallbackKey = "NavResultCallbackKey"

/**
 * Set the navigation result callback on calling screen.
 *
 * @param callback The navigation result callback.
 */
fun <T> NavController.setNavResultCallback(callback: NavResultCallback<T>) {
    currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(NavResultCallbackKey, callback)
}

/**
 *  Get the navigation result callback on called screen.
 *
 * @return The navigation result callback if the previous backstack entry exists
 */
fun <T> NavController.getNavResultCallback() : NavResultCallback<T>? {
    return previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.remove(NavResultCallbackKey)
}

/**
 *  Attempts to pop the controller's back stack and returns the result.
 *
 * @param result the navigation result
 */
fun <T> NavController.popBackStackWithResult(result: T) {
    getNavResultCallback<T>()?.invoke(result)
    popBackStack()
}

/**
 * Navigate to a route in the current NavGraph. If an invalid route is given, an
 * [IllegalArgumentException] will be thrown.
 *
 * @param route route for the destination
 * @param navResultCallback the navigation result callback
 * @param navOptions special options for this navigation operation
 * @param navigatorExtras extras to pass to the [Navigator]
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the given route is invalid
 */
fun <T> NavController.navigateForResult(
    route: String,
    navResultCallback: NavResultCallback<T>,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null,
    navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras? = null
) {
    setNavResultCallback(navResultCallback)
    navigate(route, navOptions, navigatorExtras)
}

/**
 * Navigate to a route in the current NavGraph. If an invalid route is given, an
 * [IllegalArgumentException] will be thrown.
 *
 * @param route route for the destination
 * @param navResultCallback the navigation result callback
 * @param builder DSL for constructing a new [NavOptions]
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the given route is invalid
 */
@Suppress("unused", "unused", "unused")
fun <T> NavController.navigateForResult(
    route: String,
    navResultCallback: NavResultCallback<T>,
    builder: NavOptionsBuilder.() -> Unit
) {
    setNavResultCallback(navResultCallback)
    navigate(route, builder)
}
```

And Before calling

```
 navController.navigate(route= "${MainDestinations.xxx}/${id}")
```

call

```
navController.setNavResultCallback<Unit>(callback= some callback function here)
```

Then before calling

```
 navController.navigateUp()
```

call

```
navController.getNavResultCallback<Unit>()?.invoke(Unit)
```